# How to Convert JavaScript Date to Date in Java?

Tags: java, javascript, date

I need to convert `JsDate` to `java.util.Date.` I searched but I couldn't find anything. So could you help me with this problem?

**Edit:** I do this conversion process on GWT screen. I have `Datepicker` on screen and it gives me `JsDate` value when I use it's `getValue()` method. So I'm supposed to put this value into the property of an object which has Date type.

```
ObjectName.setDate(PickerName.getValue());
```

I hope my edit will be more clear.

**Edit2:**

This line is the solution of my problem:

```
myObject.setDate(new Date((long) myPicker.getValue().getTime()));
```

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, we would be happy to help, please provide some information on what you have tried, and how your code looks like at the moment

Comment: For new readers to the question I recommend you don’t use `java.util.Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` and/or `LocalDate`. Both are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The best way of dates conversion is using time in milliseconds, UTC. Both JS Date object and java.util.Date class support conversion to milliseconds (`getTime()`) and instantiating from milliseconds (using constructor).

Comment: Your tips was very useful to solve my problem. getTime() method served my purpose. Thanks..

Comment: JS `getTime` starts from midnight January 1, 1970, so does java?

Comment: @hakunami, yes so does java (following C). The only difference is that ANSI C counts time in seconds because its `long` has only 4 bytes. Java and javascript count time in milliseconds.

Comment: you can also use new Date().toISOString() for converting it to Java Date

Answer (score 36):

You can create a `java.util.Date` object from the 'time since epoch' value of the JS `Date`

**javascript**

```
var d = new Date().getTime();
```

**java**

```
// get value from client (ajax, form, etc), and construct in Date object

long valueFromClient = ...

Date date = new Date(valueFromClient);

String formatted = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date);
```

Comment: User epoch answering a question about dates ;-)

Answer (score 15):

If people like me are forced to parse a JS-formatted date string (as the result of `(new Date()).toString()` in JavaScript), here is the SimpleDateFormat spec I used:

```
DateFormat jsfmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM d y H:m:s 'GMT'Z (zz)");
```

If you have control of the producer of the dates, I concur that using timestamps or at least `.toUTCString()` is definitely more robust.

Comment: The format that works for me is `EE MMM d y H:m:s 'GMT'z`

Answer (score 4):

### ISO 8601 and java.time

ISO 8601 is the international standard for date and time including date and time formats. About any programming language has support for it, including both JavaScript and Java.

In JavaScript produce a string in ISO 8601 format using `Date.toISOString()`. We don’t need any formatter.

```js
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.toISOString();
  console.log(n);
```

The result is somewhat human readable as long as you remember that it’s in UTC, denoted by the trailing `Z`.

In Java parse the string using `Instant.parse()`. We don’t need to specify any formatter here either.

```
    String stringFromJavaScript = "2021-07-12T05:54:03.365Z";
    Instant inst = Instant.parse(stringFromJavaScript);
    System.out.println(inst);
```

Output:

> 2021-07-12T05:54:03.365Z

The question asked for a `java.util.Date` for the result from a date picker. We should avoid using `java.util.Date` for this both because despite the name a `Date` does not represent a date and because the `Date` class is poorly designed and long outdated. For a date without time of day a `LocalDate` is appropriate:

```
    LocalDate date = inst.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    System.out.println(date);
```

In my time zone the output was:

> 2021-07-12

The conversion is time zone dependent and will only be correct if the default time zone of the JVM (or which time zone you pass to `atZone()`) is the same as used by the date picker.

If you do need a `Date` for a legacy API not yet upgraded to java.time:

```
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(inst);
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

> Mon Jul 12 07:54:03 CEST 2021

### Links

- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 3):

You may want this:

```
java:
String jsDate="2013-3-22 10:13:00";
Date javaDate=new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(jsDate);
System.out.println(javaDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the DateFormat parse method (doc can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29)). It can parse a string representation of a date and return a java.util.Date.

Answer (score 0):

JS Date --
new Date()
Wed Aug 14 2019 14:54:38 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Java Date --
new Date().toISOString()
"2019-08-14T09:25:50.136Z"