# Javascript Date-String GMT to Java Date

Tags: java, javascript, date, jersey

I am trying to write a REST-API with Jersey. From javascript I get a Datestring like:

```
Tue Oct 16 2012 07:10:55 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

(That's what

```js
new Date().toString()
```

does, but this is not in my scope.)

This date string can be parsed by implementing an own @ContextResolver. I been googling for about a day and the best SimpleDateFormat I could put together is:

```java
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'z '('z')'", Locale.ROOT);
```

But as you can see the 'GMT'-part and the brackets are "hard-coded". Is there any better solution without changing the javascript part?

Comment: are you not able to change the Javascript part?

Comment: There two facets to that question: First: It's not my code, but I could ask the other dev. Second: It means changing a lot of js-code(many of which is legacy code for a deprecated php-Backend) and would be a lot of work

Comment: Finally we changed the javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kidmenot: Thanks for the link, but that solution requires to handle the javascript-date "manually" on the java side and to change the Javascript-side. So finally we needed to change the javascript-part only. There was

```js
var myDate = new Date():
// ... many LOCs
var myDateString = "" + myDate + "";
```

scattered all over the js-code. So just changing that to

```js
var myDate = new Date():
// ... many LOCs
var myDateString = myDate;
```

solved the issue, because later on the was a

```
JSON.stringify()
```

just before sending it to the server. That *JSON.stringify()* calls *myDate.toJSON()* which returns an ISO-8601 datestring which gets processed by Jersey without the need for any further coding.

So we chose this solution to spare us from future complications.

**Edit half a year later:**

This parse problem occured often and was finally inevitable because of some js-framework.
The following is our Java-Solution:

```java
public static Date jsDateStringToJavaDate(String jsDateString) throws ParseException{

    String[] arrStrDateParts = jsDateString.split(" ");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(arrStrDateParts[5].substring(0,6)+":"+arrStrDateParts[5].substring(6)));
    return sdf.parse(arrStrDateParts[0]+" "+arrStrDateParts[1]+" "+arrStrDateParts[2]+" "+arrStrDateParts[3]+" "+arrStrDateParts[4]);       
}
```

If you got a better solution, please post it here. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You could try [toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Comment: Yepp, that output is easier to parse("MM.dd.YYYY"). But it's on the javascript side. Maybe I didn't make myself clear enough. Changes in javascript are the very last option. I am searching for an counterpart on the java side that parses the before mentioned string. Do you know any?

Comment: Since there was no further response and no other suggestions I accept your answer. Thanks for the effort. We finally changed the javascript-part to JSON.stringify(...) without calling toString() before.

Comment: @gross.jonas you can answer your own question and explain how you solved it. You could check the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722790/how-to-convert-javascript-date-to-date-in-java?rq=1) also. I have minimal experience in java, not exactly my forte.