# How to change date format in HTML5

Tags: html, date, datepicker, thymeleaf

I need to display a date in HTML(application is using HTML5+Thymeleaf).

How to convert from the below format

```
Wed Jul 01 09:09:51 IST 2015
```

To

```
Wed Jul 01 2015 09:09:51 GMT+0530 (Indian Standard Time)
```

And also , if I give `new Date()` in `controller` class, its displaying(in log) as

```
Thu Jun 11 06:41:11 IST 2015
```

But if I give `new Date()` in HTML, it is displaying(in alert) in below format.

```
Thu Jun 11 2015 06:41:12 GMT +0530 (Indian Standard Time)
```

HTML Code:

```
$('#validFrom').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
alert('validFrom ...'+new Date());
```

Can anyone help me in converting and to set date in HTML. 
Also it will be great if anyone can answer the difference of setting new Date() in controller class and HTML.

Comment: Your controller is done in Java?

Comment: Yes. controller is done in Java

Answer (score 0):

You will find this useful.
[How to Convert JavaScript Date to Date in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722790/how-to-convert-javascript-date-to-date-in-java)

Basically, Java and Javascript date formats are slightly different and you need converters and parsers.

Comment: Thanks. But I need to set in DatePicker. I found a solution to set in Date picker.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller:

```
model.addAttribute("validFromDate", validDate);
```

In HTML:

```
var validFromDate = [[${validFromDate}]];
$('#validFrom').datepicker('setDate', new Date(validFromDate));
```

Comment: Good work!. new Date(validFromDate) is parsing Java Date string and returning Javascript Date object.